# How VMware workstation determines which OS is there in the iso?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware, iso-image, vmware-workstation

**How VMware workstation determines which OS is there in the iso ?? More specifically - what files does it look for ??**

A little explanation -

When [Solus Budgie iso](https://getsol.us/download/) is selected, VMware detects it as fedora but the site nowhere mentions it is fedora based.

[image]

[Android-x86](https://www.android-x86.org/) with Linux kernel as FreeBSD

[image]

Ubuntu detected but ubuntu based distros like [Linux mint](https://linuxmint.com/) not detected

[image]

How can I make sure that my custom Linux-distro iso is detected correctly by VMware ?

---

Please note : **my question is not about how to proceed from here or how to install the desired OS using VMware**; I am asking "***how VMware detects any iso?***".

Comment: If you want to know “how” you will have to contact VMWare directly

Answer (score 0):

Do Install Later (should be the last selection. Then the next screen is the one where you select the operating system you want.

Pull it down for a long list and select the operating system closest to what you want.

Go through the settings to completion, and then select the ISO file that matches your earlier choice and install. You do the selection of ISO - VMware does not do that.

I am in VMware Workstation V16 and used that to inform the settings I posted above. See some screen shots below. Follow through all the screens, save the machine, and then go back and select the ISO and install.

[image]

[image]

[image]